# "rails server" does not work but command prompt says it has though there's no page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
c:\mowes\www\rails_projects\first_app>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-10-17 16:49:22] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-10-17 16:49:22] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]
[2013-10-17 16:49:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11400 port=3000
```

When I go to `0.0.0.0:3000` I get this
[image: cannot find server]

I did not use RailsInstaller and am using a portable version of Ruby and Rails.

Comment: did you try `http://127.0.0.1:3000` or `http://localhost:3000` not sure if 0 works on windows

Comment: No I did not do any of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` just means that it's listening on all addresses that the machine has. Try browsing to `http://localhost:3000/` instead.